# Docker container network: Unable to establish connection between two containers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have created two containers; one is running the spring boot eureka name server and the other one is running java app. The two containers are on the same bridge network.

```
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
4554021e2f79   docker_ambuli     bridge    local
```

Shortened output from `docker container ls`:

```
0de2fa36c342   ambuli/ms-1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   
878eb80bc7e4  ambuli/ms-2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp, :::8761->8761/tcp
```

IP Addresses of the containers:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 0de2fa36c342
172.27.0.3

docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 878eb80bc7e4
172.27.0.2
```

`docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' 4554021e2f79` is saying the two containers are on this
network.

All seems to be fine. However, the Java throws exception saying connection timeout.
Tracing through wireshark, I can see that SYN messages are sent from 172.27.0.3(myService) to 172.27.0.2(nameing-server).  But, there is no reply.

The java error is:
exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to naming-server:8761 [naming-server/172.28.0.2] failed: Connection timed out

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks very much.

I have the following yaml file:

```
    version: '3'
    
    services:
      naming-server:
        image: ambuli/ms1-naming-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        mem_limit: 700m
        ports:
          - "8761:8761"
        networks:
          - ambuli
          
      my-service:
        image: ambuli/ms1-myservice:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        mem_limit: 700m
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        networks:
          - ambuli
        links:
          - naming-server 
        depends_on:
          - naming-server
        environment:
          EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server:8761/eureka
    networks:
      ambuli:
```